# Angular JS filter ng-repeat with field AND dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have seen a lot of conflicting answers on the web about this, but I am looking for the most succinct way to accomplish this.

I have data that is a list of countries of the world, including, name, ISO alpha code, region of the world, etc.

I have an ng-repeat in a table to display this:

`<tr ng-repeat="i in filteredItems = (iso3166 | filter: countryFilter)">`

I have a text field and a dropdown that needs to filter the list.

The text field is supposed to filter by country name:  either by matching the ISO alpha code or the country name.

```
<input type="text" id="countrySearch" placeholder="Country" ng-model="countryQuery">
```

This works with this in the Controller:

```
    $scope.countryFilter = function (value) {
      if (angular.isUndefined($scope.countryQuery) || $scope.countryQuery === '') {
        return true;
      }
       return value.name.indexOf($scope.countryQuery) >= 0 || value.alpha_2.indexOf($scope.countryQuery) >= 0;
    };
```

The bane of my existence is how to bring the dropdown into the mix.  The dropdown is using an array of objects with values for regions of the world, as in

```
$scope.regionMenu = [
    {
      label: 'Show All',
      value: ''
    },
    {
      label: 'EU',
      value: 'Europe'
    },...
```

and

```
<select ng-model="region" ng-options="s.value as s.label for s in regionMenu"></select>
```

The goal is to have the input field work together, so the filteredItems would show a row if the value typed in matches:

(ISO alpha-2 OR Name) AND (region chosen in menu)

Any help on how to edit the `countryFilter` function or to totally rewrite it to accomplish this much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two options:

#### Solution 1: Chain another filter

*This solution is easier, but is less efficient, since you can end up scanning all the elements in the array twice (instead of once in solution 2)*.

Controller:

```
$scope.regionFilter = function (value) {
  if (angular.isUndefined($scope.region) || $scope.region === '') {
    return true;
  }
  return value.region === $scope.region;
};
```

Template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in filteredItems = (iso3166 | filter: countryFilter | filter: regionFilter)">
```

#### Solution 2: Join the filters

```
$scope.countryFilter = function (value) {
  var passCountry;
  if (angular.isUndefined($scope.countryQuery) || $scope.countryQuery === '') {
    passCountry = true;
  }
  else {
    passCountry = value.name.indexOf($scope.countryQuery) >= 0 || value.alpha_2.indexOf($scope.countryQuery) >= 0;
  }

  var passRegion;
  if (angular.isUndefined($scope.region) || $scope.region === '') {
    passRegion = true;
  }
  else {
    passRegion = value.region === $scope.region;
  }

  return passCountry && passRegion;
};
```